# Unity проблема с Animation Rigging

Tags: unity3d, анимация, animator

У меня проблема с IK и анимацией. Когда я хочу отредактировать анимацию в режиме воспроизведения и нажимаю на предварительный просмотр или запись, скелет модели перемещается, и Rig Builder, кажется, перестает работать. С такой проблемой редактировать анимацию практически невозможно. Когда я выполнял точно такие же действия в другом проекте, такой проблемы не возникало. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Видео с проблемой: https://youtu.be/99U9qKLfA3U

Я добавил IK к слоям в Animator. Я отключил свой скрипт, который менял положение рук в игре. Я попытался отредактировать анимацию, добавив ключевые кадры. Ничто из этого не помогло.